# How to redirect all incoming packets to sniffer in Linux using iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp

I need to redirect all incoming tcp packets from eth0 to current host (change ip address from 1.1.1.1 to 1.1.1.2) and outgoing tcp packets from sniffer from eth1 to another host(from 2.2.2.2 to 2.2.2.1). Is it possible to communicate this two hosts between each other throught my sniffer program?

Answer (score 0):

The next three commands can put all incoming packets from two ip addresses to current host

$iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.2:1234
$iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 2.2.2.1 -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:1234
$iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE